# Is it a good practice that components has it's own state independently from Redux's sigle state tree?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am refactoring an application from Flux to Redux. As Redux says, it has a single state tree for the whole application's state. Before this refactor, most components work only using props and using state on container components, but certain key-components in my app, have its own state for visual purposes independently from Redux's single state tree.

One of the components is [React-Dropzone-Component](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component/) which has its own state (if you look to its code) but I have other components that are non-third-party and, as React-Dropzone-Component, they have their own state (for visual purposes as previously said).

My question is if it's ok that those components have their own state? or should I move the state of those components to the main state that Redux proposes?

If I have to move those components state to the Redux's state, am I not forcing those components to work only on single state tree environments?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with having component state in a Redux app. So long as:

1. Other parts of the component hierarchy have no need to know about these state variables
2. It's not duplicating Redux state

A good example would be trivial UI stuff, like show/hide functionality.* I'm not familiar with React Dropzone but it seems to fit this category.

(*But that's not say all UI logic belongs in local state; sometimes it will need to be in the store.)